# Compare time to separate days

Tags: php, datetime

I have some DB entries, they have timestamps. And all I want is to draw a separate line between days. And also, I need the day to start not at 00:00, but at 07:00. It's like an offset for the day start.

Now I have that (for context):

```
foreach($logs as $log) {
    $cur_date = $log[0]['timestamp'];
    echo "<p>".$log[0]['content']."</p>";
}
```

Is there a simple workaround for the problem I've described?

Thank you!

Comment: use strtotime($cur_date);

Comment: strtotime() would work, also you could extract the hour in MySQL directly `HOUR(timestamp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$prev_date = 0;
foreach($logs as $log) {
    $cur_date = strtotime($log[0]['timestamp']);
    $cur_day_beginning = strtotime(date("Y-m-d 07:00:00", $cur_date));

    if ($cur_date >= $cur_day_beginning && $prev_date < $cur_day_beginning) {
        echo "<hr/>";
    }

    $prev_date = $cur_date;

    echo "<p>".$log[0]['content']."</p>";
}
```